# if count == 0 AND otherCount == 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, counter

I have 2 counters "goFoods" and "count". I want an if statement that checks to see if goFoods have reached 9 **AND** the count is more than 6, then make the TryAgain div visible. I've tried this, but it isn't working.

```
function checkTryAgain() {
    if(goFoods == 9; && count >= 6; ){
    $("#TryAgain").css({visibility: 'visible',});
    
}}
```

Comment: semicolons don't belong there.

Comment: What he said. `if(goFoods == 9 && count >= 6 )`

Comment: try something like `if (goFoods === 9 && count >= 6) { $('#TryAgain').show() } else { $('#TryAgain').hide() }`

Comment: Or `$('#TryAgain').toggle(goFoods === 9 && count >= 6);`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan even better :-)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It works fine if you remove the semicolons from the if statement:

```js
let goFoods = 9, count = 6

function checkTryAgain() {
    if(goFoods == 9 && count >= 6){
    $("#TryAgain").css({visibility: 'visible',});
    
}}

checkTryAgain()
```

```css
#TryAgain{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="TryAgain">Try Again</div>
```